# Delete a record in database cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have the config `'prefix' => 'hq_'`,
and I created a table : `hq_products(pd_id, pd_price, pd_name,pd_date)`.

In controller, I want to delete a product. I used:

```
$productId = (int) $this->params['url']['id'];
$this->Product->deleteAll(array('Product.pd_id' => $productId));
```

and received the error :

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Product.id' in 'field list' [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]

Query:

```
SELECT `Product`.`id` FROM `hq_products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`pd_id` = 1
```

I also used : `$this->Product->delete($productId);` same error.

Please help me.

Comment: Show us your table structure. Anyway, are you sure you have a id field in your table?

Comment: Your error message says `Product.id` for the unknown field, but you're using `Product.pd_id` in the queries?

Comment: Your query is `SELECT`, but it should be `DELETE`. Are you sure you pasted the correct query?

Answer (score 2):

In your *Product* model, you need to configure the `$primaryKey` [model attribute](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html):

```
class Product extends AppModel {
    var $primaryKey = 'pd_id';
}
```

CakePHP expects the primary key in your `hq_products` table to be `id`, but you have named it `pd_id`. You need to inform CakePHP whenever you deviate from the [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html).